# Parse Error Retrieved JsonArrayRequest Using PHP to RecyclerView On Fragments Volley

Tags: java, php, android, json, android-fragments

I'm practicing implementing `recyclerView` (my first time), on `Fragments`, and I want to retrieve those data from my server (phpMyAdmin). I have a little background with php and mysql. All I want is to fetch my data in a very simple way, displaying my data in a `cardView` - `recyclerView`. As I review my java code it seems right now (After being corrected).

As I debug my app, I found that it will not go to my `onResponse` instead it go to `ErrorResponse`. **How do I parse this right?**

Here's my Fragment: **OrganizationAboutFragment .java**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.recycler_view, container, false);

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    orgListAdapter = new OrgListAdapter(organizationDataList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(orgListAdapter);
    //GET DATA REQUEST
    parseJSONData();

    return recyclerView;
}

public void parseJSONData(){
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArray = new JsonArrayRequest(ServerScripts.PHP_SCRIPT_PATH + ServerScripts.PHP_GET_FEEDS, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            if (response.length() > 0){
                try {
                    organizationDataList.clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++ ){
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        OrganizationData organizationData = new OrganizationData();

                        //SQL TABLE NAME
                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("orgName")){
                            organizationData.orgName = jsonObject.getString("orgName");
                        }

                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("orgDesc")){
                            organizationData.orgDesc = jsonObject.getString("orgDesc");
                        }

                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("orgCategory")){
                            organizationData.orgCategory = jsonObject.getString("orgCategory");
                        }

                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("orgCurrentMembers")){
                            organizationData.orgCurrentMembers = jsonObject.getInt("orgCurrentMembers");
                        }

                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("orgMaxMembers")){
                            organizationData.orgMaxMembers = jsonObject.getInt("orgMaxMembers");
                        }

                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("orgType")){
                            organizationData.orgType = jsonObject.getString("orgType");
                        }
                        //ADD
                        organizationDataList.add(organizationData);
                    }
                        //NOTIFY
                        orgListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }

    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonArray);
```

My Adapter: **OrgListAdapter.java**

```
public class OrgListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrgListAdapter.OrgViewHolder>{

private List<OrganizationData> mOrganizationData;

public OrgListAdapter(List<OrganizationData> mOrganizationData){
    this.mOrganizationData = mOrganizationData;
}

@Override
public OrgViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_cardview_flat_organizations,parent,false);
    OrgViewHolder myOrgViewHolder = new OrgViewHolder(view);

    return myOrgViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(OrgViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //ORG MODELS PASS TO CARD VIEW - HOLDER
    holder.appCompatTextViewName.setText(mOrganizationData.get(position).getOrgName());
    holder.appCompatTextViewCategory.setText(mOrganizationData.get(position).getOrgCategory());
    holder.appCompatTextViewDesc.setText(mOrganizationData.get(position).getOrgDesc());
    holder.appCompatTextViewJoinMembers.setText(mOrganizationData.get(position).getOrgCurrentMembers());
    holder.appCompatTextViewMaxMembers.setText(mOrganizationData.get(position).getOrgMaxMembers());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (mOrganizationData != null){
        return mOrganizationData.size();
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}


public static class OrgViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    CardView cardViewOrg;
    AppCompatTextView appCompatTextViewName;
    AppCompatTextView appCompatTextViewDesc;
    AppCompatTextView appCompatTextViewJoinMembers;
    AppCompatTextView appCompatTextViewMaxMembers;
    AppCompatTextView appCompatTextViewCategory;


    AppCompatImageView appCompatImageViewOrgType;
    String getDataStoredUniqueId = "";

    //Buttons
    AppCompatButton appCompatButtonJoin;
    AppCompatButton appCompatButtonFollow;
    AppCompatButton appCompatButtonReadMore;

    public OrgViewHolder(View getView){
        super(getView);

        cardViewOrg = (CardView) getView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_org);
        appCompatTextViewName = (AppCompatTextView) getView.findViewById(R.id.textViewOrgName);
        appCompatTextViewCategory = (AppCompatTextView) getView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCategory);
        appCompatTextViewDesc = (AppCompatTextView) getView.findViewById(R.id.textViewOrgShortDesc);
        appCompatTextViewJoinMembers = (AppCompatTextView) getView.findViewById(R.id.currentMembers);
        appCompatTextViewMaxMembers = (AppCompatTextView) getView.findViewById(R.id.maxMembers);
        appCompatImageViewOrgType = (AppCompatImageView) getView.findViewById(R.id.orgTypeIndicator);

        //Buttons
        appCompatButtonJoin = (AppCompatButton) getView.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonJoined);
        appCompatButtonFollow = (AppCompatButton) getView.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonFollow);
        appCompatButtonReadMore = (AppCompatButton) getView.findViewById(R.id.buttonMoreOrg);

    }

}
```

My php code: **orgList.php**

```
<?php

//if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == ''){


     require('dbConnect.php');

     $SQLi_ORG_FEEDS = "SELECT organizationName,organizationDescription,organizationCategory,
                        organizationCurrentMembers,organizationMaxMembersNo,organizationType FROM org_information";

     $query = mysqli_query($dbConnect,$SQLi_ORG_FEEDS) or die("Error".mysqli_error($dbConnect));

     $checkRow = mysqli_num_rows($query);

     $response = array();

     if($checkRow > 0){
         while ($getRecord = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $response["organizationName"] = $getRecord;
            $response["organizationType"] = $getRecord;
            $response["organizationDescription"] = $getRecord;  
            $response["organizationCategory"] = $getRecord;
            $response["organizationCurrentMembers"] = $getRecord;
            $response["organizationMaxMembersNo"] = $getRecord;                
         }

         echo json_encode($response);
     }

//}
```

[image: ParseError]

Comment: also not initializing `organizationDataList `

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K yes right

Answer (score 2):

In the `onResponse` of your `parseJSONData`, you create a new `OrganizationData` object and parse properly, however you never add this object to any list.

You're missing `organizationDataList.add(organizationData);` in your for loop.

Another tip would be to either call `notifyItemInserted` right after this, or move your `notifyDataSetChanged` after the loop :)

Comment: In my php code, is it right? I also doubt that it was caused by my phpCode.. I'll check my for loop. Thank you for your time.

Comment: SIr, can you help me with this one? The error in the picture.

Comment: Well I'm not familiar with Php, however the error shown seems to be because the format returned by your server is not correctly formatted, or not json formatted. As suggested here ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/25493444/4706693 ), try to install `RESTClient ` and see what's going on

Comment: thank you for your answer, yes, I'm trying that one now, using postman.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line in your for loop

organizationDataList.add(organizationData);

orgListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // after loop

Comment: Still I got no response. :(

Comment: @RoCk did you initialize organizationDataList? and debug your parseJSONData() you will get it

Comment: Is this what your mean? ArrayList<OrganizationData> organizationDataList = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: @RoCk yea this one

Comment: I added those code and modify my - (for loop) , still get no feeds. I believe this something to do with the php code.

Comment: yea thats why i told to debug and check whether data is coming or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113498/discussion-between-nisarg-and-rock).

Answer (score 0):

Try Using Retrofit. It faster then volley and you will not need to parse your JSON(Standard JSON Response). As retrofit only accepts Standard JSON format. You have to pass the Main MODEL class to store data. Here is the Great tutorial. You will never have to parse the JSON. Just use and get the data from response.body.yourPOJO();

Try this if it helps.

http://www.androidwarriors.com/2015/12/retrofit-20-android-example-web.html